# Get date of last saturday - BusyBox 1.1.0

Tags: date, sh, busybox

Since the date in BusyBox is not as powerful as *gnu date*, I have problems to calculate the date of last saturday.

```
last_sat=`date +"%Y-%m-%d" -d "last saturday"`
```

only works fine with gnu date.

I've found something like this to calculate from Epoch

```
busybox date -D '%s' -d "$(( `busybox date +%s`+3*60 ))"
```

but my BusyBox (v1.1.0) doesn't recognize the `-D` argument.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the last Saturday before today, under busybox 1.16:

```
date -d "UTC 1970-01-01 $(date +"%s - 86400 - %w * 86400"|xargs expr) secs"
```

How it works: take the current date in seconds, subtract one day, subtract one day times the number of the current weekday, then convert those seconds back to a date.

EDIT: after hacking together a build of 1.1, this works:

```
date -d "1970.01.01-00:00:$(date +"%s - 86400 - %w * 86400"|xargs expr)"
```

This working version is based on code-reading:

```
} else if (t = *tm_time, sscanf(t_string, "%d.%d.%d-%d:%d:%d", &t.tm_year,
                    &t.tm_mon, &t.tm_mday, 
                    &t.tm_hour, &t.tm_min,
                        &t.tm_sec) == 6) {
    t.tm_year -= 1900;  /* Adjust years */
    t.tm_mon -= 1;  /* Adjust dates from 1-12 to 0-11 */
```

Comment: This works for me using GNU date, but not the one in my old busybox host. What version of busybox are you running?

Comment: 1.16 is the oldest one I have and I don't have a system that can build 1.1 without extensive modification. Is the problem with `date`, `xargs`, `expr`, or  perhaps the shell?

Comment: @ghoti can you try again? I managed to build 1.1 on OS X (badly) and think I found an answer for you.

Comment: Alas no, `%F-%T` is not a format understood by my `busybox date`. The only format it seems to accept is `MMDDhhmmYYYY.ss`. And it only understands the first two digits of `ss`. I don't see how this can be used to *adjust* dates, only reformat existing ones.

Comment: Also, are you sure your `date` command is the reduced one from busybox, and you're not running GNU date by accident? Try adding a `busybox` to the beginning of your `date` command, and check the result of `date --version`.

Comment: I'm 100% certain. I had the darn thing running under `lldb` stepping through code. It's not using %F directly but rather the code snippet in the answer. Look at the scanf. There are build options that can affect the behavior though. `./busybox date -d "1970.01.01-00:00:$(./busybox date +"%s - 86400 - %w * 86400"|./busybox xargs ./busybox expr)"` => `Sat Sep  3 12:21:24 EDT 2016` code is from https://busybox.net/downloads/busybox-1.1.0.tar.bz2

Comment: Thank you Eric, this was really helpfull!

Answer (score 1):

BusyBox's date command has been the topic of [some discussion](http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/busybox/2011-January/074348.html) over the years. Apparently it doesn't always work as documented, and it doesn't always work the same as previous versions.

On a BB system I administer running BusyBox v1.01, I'm able to use the `-d` option with dates in the format `MMDDhhmmYYYY.ss`, and in no other format that I've tried.  Luckily, output formats work as expected, presumably because `date` is using a proper `strftime()` according to [comments in the source](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/coreutils/date.c?h=1_19_stable).

Here's my forward-and-reverse example:

```
[~] # busybox date '+%m%d%H%M%Y.%S'
090500152016.41
[~] # busybox date -d 090500152016.41
Mon Sep  5 00:15:41 EDT 2016
```

So .. what can we do with this? It seems that we can't do an arbitrary adjustment of seconds, as it only reads the first two digits:

```
[~] # busybox date -d 123119001969.65 '+%s'
65
[~] # busybox date -d 123119001969.100 '+%s'
10
```

Well, it turns out you can load the date fields with "invalid" numbers.

```
[~] # busybox date  090100002016
Thu Sep  1 00:00:00 EDT 2016
[~] # busybox date  093400002016
Wed Oct  4 00:00:00 EDT 2016
[~] # busybox date  09-200002016
Mon Aug 29 00:00:00 EDT 2016
```

So let's adjust the "day" field using something based on `%w`.

```
today=$(busybox date '+%m%d%H%M%Y')
last_sat=$(busybox date -d "${today:0:2}$( printf '%02d' $(( 10#${today:2:2} - 1 - $(busybox date '+%w') )) )${today:4}" '+%F')
```

This simply subtracts numbers in the second field (the 3rd and 4th characters of the date string). It obviously requires that your shell either be `bash` or understand bash-style math notation (`$((...))`). Math-wise, it should work as long as "last saturday" is within the same month, and it MAY work (I haven't tested it) with rollvers to the previous month (per the last test above).

Rather than jumping through these burning hoops, I recommend you just install a GNU date binary, and don't use busybox for this one binary. :-P

Good luck!

Comment: I see you're using 1.01, rather that 1.1.0. Perhaps that accounts for the discrepancy you're seeing?

Comment: @Eric - yes, I would expect so. As I mentioned at the top of my answer, there appears to have been some shift over time in the list of features supported by busybox's `date`. I haven't looked at the history of the source in too much detail, but the impact is likely that for a solution that is portable amongst different BB versions, one should aim for the lowest common denomenator. That said, I don't know how common my version is -- it's in use on an ancient QNAP file server in my office, long overdue for replacement. :)